# javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: Cannot resolve element with ID SAML-

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, xml-parsing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, saml-2.0

I am trying to parse SAML response with signature using Java.I get an exception

```
javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException:  
com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot 
resolve element with ID SAML-
```

Upon investigation there is bug in Java after the 1.7 u25 versions.The reference is below

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7094155.

Could anybody point me how to correct this error,as I am using AWS Beanstalk(which has support only for 1.7 u 25 and that too only Linux.)

Here is the starting code for reading the SAML and parsing,actually i need to validate the SAML along with signature.

```
  ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(resp.getBytes());
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder;


    try {
        docBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();      
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(bis);
        Node nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS,"Signature").item(0);
                   .....
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are encountering this issue;

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8017169

I work around this for verifying saml responses by doing something like

```
NodeList elList = this.document.getElementsByTagName("saml:Assertion");
if (elList != null && elList.getLength() > 0) {
    Attr id = ((Element)elList.item(0)).getAttributeNode("ID");
    IdResolver.registerElementById((Element)elList.item(0), id);
    log.debug("registered id: " + id + " for element: " + (Element)elList.item(0));
}
```

Just before the validation. There is probably a more elegant solution though.

Answer (score 2):

I use the JDK's XPath 1.0 implementation to process SAML responses and this code worked for me:

```
Element signature = (Element) xp.evaluate("//dsig:Signature", root, XPathConstants.NODE);
DOMValidateContext ctx = new DOMValidateContext(_cert.getPublicKey(), signature);            
NodeList idAttributes = (NodeList) xp.evaluate("//*[@ID]", root, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < idAttributes.getLength(); i++) {
    ctx.setIdAttributeNS((Element) idAttributes.item(i), null, "ID");
}
XMLSignatureFactory sigF = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
XMLSignature xmlSignature = sigF.unmarshalXMLSignature(ctx);

if (xmlSignature.validate(ctx)) {
...
```